# What should I do after $\chi^2$ test of heterogeneity? ruining binomial test as post hoc?

Tags: chi-squared-test, binomial-distribution, post-hoc

I ran a χ2 test of heterogeneity to test whether I can pool data related to the frequency of occurrence of 2 phenotypes of an insect which was sampled during different seasons. In other words, we recorded frequency of occurrence of 2 phenotype of an insect during winter, fall, spring and summer. We believe that in all seasons occurrence of two phenotype should occur in a 1:1 ratio. However, after running  χ2 test of heterogeneity we found that in three seasons one type of phenotype occur more than another one which means they are not in 1:1 ratio. now I am going to plot my data and show that a special trend occurs in some seasons and then we can not pool data. I think I should run binomial test but I am not sure I have  to test probability of occurrence of two phenotype in each season against 50% (0.5) or no! I have to test probability of occurrence of each phenotype in each season  against 50%/8=6.25% as we test 8 groups (two phenotype in each of for season)? Overall, what should be probability of binomial test?

Comment: Indeed, some people ruin binomial tests; but I don't recommend it. :)  I'll try to give a serious answer shortly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A test on homogeneity tests whether a set of proportions are equal to one another -- not necessarily that all of them are equal to .50. So if you indeed ran a homogeneity test, I question whether it was the right test to do.

I'm going to make up some numbers just to make this a bit more concrete. Suppose you observed these counts:

```
             Spg  Sum  Win  Fal
Phenotype 1   10   30   15   60
Phenotype 2   30   10   35   40
```

If your theory really says that there should be a 1:1 ratio in each season, then the "expected" counts in the chi^2 test should be:

```
             Spg  Sum  Win  Fal
Phenotype 1   20   20   25   50
Phenotype 2   20   20   25   50
```

i.e., the season totals should match the data, but they are divided equally between the two phenotypes. Compute the usual Pearson chi-square, $\sum (o-e)^2/e$. The critical value should be obtained from the $\chi^2_4$ distribution: 4 d.f., not 3 like in the homogeneity test, because there is 1 d.f. for each season but you don't lose a d.f. from estimating a common proportion.

Another thing that may help your intuition for future such questions: the "expected" counts must always sum to the "observed" counts, no matter what.